# Get ip address from stun server

Tags: stun, xirsys

I have stun server on xirsys.
How can I know what is my public address + port that I can ping to it from outside the network to my pc through NAT?

Comment: Stuntman comes with a client program that you can run to do a binding test with a stun server to discover your own public address.  just type `stunclient hostname` where `hostname` is the name or ip address of your server.  (e.g. `stunclient.exe stun.stunprotocol.org` ) You can build it from source for Linux/Unix or use the pre-compiled binaries for Windows and Mac.  http://www.stunprotocol.org

Comment: @selbie Every time I run it, I get different port in `Mapped address`. Why it is happening?

Comment: Because everytime you run stunclient, it picks a different random port from your OS and your NAT maps it to a different NAT port each time. If you want to use a specific port, use the `--localport` command line option.  Example: `stunclient --localport 9999 stun.stunprotocol.org`  More details by typing `stunclient --help`